# Re-using parameters passed to node-postgres upsert query

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, upsert, node-postgres

I'm using [`node-pg`](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres) and I've decided to refactor some code that would first make a select query to see if a record exists and then make a second query to either insert or update a record.

Suppose the following table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_schema.user_profile (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    user_id BIGINT REFERENCES %%.user (id) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    media_url VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'utc'),
    updated_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT (NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'utc')
);
```

I've landed on something like the below,

```js
const request = {
    userId: 123,
    mediaUrl: 'https://...'
};
const query = `
    INSERT INTO my_schema.user_profile
        (user_id, media_url)
    VALUES
        ($1, $2)
    ON CONFLICT (user_id)
        DO UPDATE SET (
            updated_at,
            media_url
        ) = (
            CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
            $1
        )
`;

const values = [
    request.userId,
    request.mediaUrl
];

const result = await client.query(query, values);
```

However the problem here is that `values` is valid only for the insert part of the query. If a record exists that needs to be updated, then this array of values is not correct, it would have to be:

```js
const values = [
    request.mediaUrl,
];
```

But then `node-pg` will start complaining about the update portion of the query having more columns being updated than paramterized provided.

How would I be able to get something like this to work?

Comment: What? If you update, you want to store the mediaUrl in userId and vice versa?

Comment: No.. I'm trying to insert a record and provide the values for `user_id` and `media_url`. If a record already happens to exists with the provided `user_id` (as I've specified in the `on conflict` clause), then I'd like to update that record by `user_id` and set a new value for `updated_at` and `media_url`

Comment: But that's what your statement is already doing (except that you should remove the `WHERE` clause).

Comment: I've removed the `where` clause, but the problem is still in the fact that `$1` is going to get mapped to `values[0]` (which is `request.userId`). I need it to map to `request.mediaUrl`. And now that I've removed the `where user_id = $2` part, `node-pg` will start complaining about the `update` portion of the query and the fact that there are more values provided than columns being updated

Comment: It seems like you want `DO UPDATE SET (updated_at, media_url) = (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, $2)`? Nothing says the the parameters have to occur in the query only once or in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const request = {
    userId: 123,
    mediaUrl: 'https://...'
};
const query = `
    INSERT INTO my_schema.user_profile
        (user_id, media_url)
    VALUES
        ($1, $2)
    ON CONFLICT (user_id)
        DO UPDATE SET
            updated_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
            media_url  = excluded.media_url
`;

const values = [
    request.userId,
    request.mediaUrl
];

const result = await client.query(query, values);
```

1. The scope of the `update` taking place in the [`on conflict`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) clause is already limited to the context of the conflicting row, it's not a full-fledged, standalone `update` that you'd have to specifically target to get there, so the `where` ([now removed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77620324/1)) was unnecessary.
2. You're free to reorder the update column list.
3. When value order is problematic, you can swap out the parenthesized syntax in place of comma separated `column=new_value` pairs.
4. You can re-use a value from your `insert` payload by addressing it as `excluded.media_url`: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WCdW93gX)

   ```sql
   prepare insert_s(bigint,text) as
   INSERT INTO my_schema.user_profile
           (user_id, media_url)
       VALUES
           ($1, $2)
       ON CONFLICT (user_id)
           DO UPDATE SET (
               updated_at,
               media_url
           ) = (
               CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC',
               excluded.media_url
           )
   RETURNING *;

   execute insert_s(1,'example.com/a_completely_new_pic.jpg');
   ```

   | id | user_id | media_url | created_at | updated_at |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 1 | example.com/a_completely_new_pic.jpg | 2023-12-07 13:53:14.593296 | 2023-12-07 13:53:15 |